# get data function inside get data function, Firestore

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore

Firebase is asynchronous 
but I really need some data from my Firestore Database and to use fetch some
another data again
so what I did is this

```
db.collection("").document("").get(){
 @Override
 public void OnSuccess(.....){

    db.collection("").document("").get().....

 }
}
```

is this no problem??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks fairly normal to me, especially if the data you're getting in the inner `get()` depends on the data you got from the outer `get()`.

If you find yourself reading hundreds of documents this way, it's typically a good moment to consider if you should be duplicating some data to the "outer document". This type of trade-off of data duplication vs number of reads is quite common in NoSQL databases.

For more on the topic of data modeling, see:

- this article on [NoSQL data modeling](https://highlyscalable.wordpress.com/2012/03/01/nosql-data-modeling-techniques/)
- the [Firebase for SQL developers](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLl-K7zZEsYLlP-k-RKFa7RyNPa9_wCH2s) video series. Even though it was created for the Firebase Realtime Database, many of the mappings also apply to Cloud Firestore.
- the [Get to know Cloud Firestore](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLl-K7zZEsYLluG5MCVEzXAQ7ACZBCuZgZ) video series, which was made specifically for Cloud Firestore.